# How to send headers?

Tags: typescript, authorization, bearer-token, nestjs

I am trying to send the header of an bearer authorization but it doesn't works.

Here my code

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: '/index', 
        headers: { 
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTU0NjQ0OTc4NiwiZXhwIjoxNTQ3MDU0NTg2fQ.AAK7M4d8QenFJGxuiOsK8sIwdP2otUxkgZdtkMHXvuw'
        }, 
        method: 'GET'
    });
```

Also in Postman the token works

[image: Postman request]

but in the view no authorization is send.

Comment: In postman you send the request to `/Curso/index` and in your ajax request to `/index`. Is that a problem?

Comment: The code works in a /Curso/create, where I don't need any authorization, but where I need it, It doesn't works. Show me some error that say " Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at <anonymous>:1:3"

Comment: This sounds like jquery is not available. Can you make sure that jquery is included?

Comment: On the console of chrome works, and shows correctly the preview, but in the create view, In the index view just get the error 403

Comment: Can you post more code? When are you making the ajax call? On what route are you, when you make the ajax call? Without more information it seems hard to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, this is my code https://github.com/luisssebas/Project